# Apple product list price and purchase dialog price both are showing different

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

My product list are dynamic, name and price both are coming from app store.
I have only one product and that original app store product price is 9,99€ Tier 8.

```
await inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_kIds).productDetails;
```

When I get this product in my iOS app at that time product details price is 8,99€.

```
 viewModel
          .getInstance()
          .buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: viewModel.initPurchaseProducts())
          .whenComplete(() {})
          .catchError((onError) {
        showToast(Constants.purchaseFail, success: 0);
        print("catch error error $onError");
      });
```

When I call buyNonConsumable function then this purchase dialog show 9,99€

I am testing on TestFlight and xCode. The IAP is not on production.

I have used this package : https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase

Dart Version : 2.18.4

Flutter SDK : 3.8.8

Application snap

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about this price difference problem? Any suggestion would be most appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: For sandbox or production? Did you modify the price recently?

Comment: I am testing sandbox account and I haven't change price.

Comment: Hmm, no ideas then, sorry. I am also using `in_app_purchase` and query the price from the store. I get the correct price in both sandbox and production.